# Не обрабатывается форма

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ckeditor

У меня есть html форма, я хочу при выборе данных из select что бы загружались данные в textarea.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я выбираю select, данные передаются по аяксу в другой файл там обрабатывается запрос и должна выходить информация.

Форма текста

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Текст ответа на претензию </label>
    <textarea id="editor1" name="text" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea> <br>
</div>
```

Cам select

```
<div class="form-group">
        <select name="page"  class="form-control">
            <label>Форма загрузки шаблона</label>
            <option value="">- Выберите шаблон -</option>
            <?php echo $shops; ?>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default clicka"> Загрузить шаблон</button>
</div>
```

аякс форма

```
$("body").on("click", ".clicka", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clickedIDpw = $('select[name="page"]').val();
    var ur = "template_paste.php";
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: ur,
        dataType:'html',
        data: {clickedIDps: clickedIDpw},
        success:function(data) {
            $("#editor1").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

это php который обрабатывает аякс и выводит информацию

```
if(!isset($_GET['clickedIDps'])){
    clickedIDps = $_GET['clickedIDps'];
} else {
    clickedIDps = $_GET["clickedIDps"];
}

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'логин', 'пароль', 'имя бд');
$sqldata = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM teamplate WHERE name=clickedIDps");
$dats = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata);

echo $dats{'text'};
```

Но вместо корректно работы у меня выходит ошибка 500 
в консоли `/template_paste.php?clickedIDps=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7`

Почему не обрабатывается форма? Помогите, пожалуйста.
Или как сделать мне что бы при выборе шаблона из select мне в textarea загружался текст из базы данных?

Comment: Что за `editor` используется?

Comment: @And я использую ckeditor

Comment: Отлично! Тогда используйте метод [setData()](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-setData)

Answer (score 0):

Первое что бросается в глаза - для установки value в текстовые input в JQ используется .val: В ajax, где выполняется замена значений в textarea попробуйте написать так:

```
$(#editor1).val(data);
```

Comment: проверил, не помогло=(

Comment: У визуальных редакторов вы так не сделаете. Иначе, было-бы, все очень просто подменить.

Comment: @and я отключил визуальный редактор и у меня не получилось